# Scroll to accordion from a nav-link and open it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 bootstrap accordions all collapsed. When clicking from navigation link ([href="#headingTwo"] etc...] I need to expand that referenced accordion only. [ AND close it if clicked on another navigation link ]

So the below code works but I'm repeating it 4 times.... Surely it can be simplified into one function?

```
// accordion 1
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href="#headingTwo"]').on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("collapseTwo").classList.add("show");
});

// accordion 2
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href="#headingThree"]').on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("collapseThree").classList.add("show");
});

// accordion 3
$[...]

// accordion 4
$[...]
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your anchor share the same class `.js-scroll-trigger`, you could assign the click handler to all of them, within the handler you will get the target accordion item from the anchor's `href`, that it's the `id` of the accordion item, then you can just trigger the `click` handler of the item button like below.

`href` contains the accordion header `id`, the element contains as it's first child a `button` that triggers the expand/collapse

```
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
  <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    Accordion Item #1
  </button>
</h2>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("a.js-scroll-trigger").on("click", function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");

    $(target).find("button").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#headingOne" class="js-scroll-trigger">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#headingTwo" class="js-scroll-trigger">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#headingThree" class="js-scroll-trigger">Item 3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! And many thanks for taking the time to explain in detail and provide example, very useful. Really appreciate. Thanks again

Comment: Although this is the correct fix but if the anchor is on another page it doesn't work...?

Comment: @riospereira you could put this script in a js file and put that file on both pages, that will work as long it has the same class on the anchor of the second page